# EasyUI After Expand & JQuery Animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-easyui

I need to perform an action after a Jquery animation has occurred.
I know this is possible using a callback function but here is the kicker: I am using EasyUI framework. My function is plugged into a layout "OnExpand" event.

From their documentation, this event says it takes place AFTER the expand event occurs but it infact does not. It is not synchronised with the animation... therefore it triggers before the animation event completes.

I don't know if there is any way around this... any ideas would be greatly appreciated...
I have tried accessing EasyUI forums but they are not approving my request to join.

Thank you

```
$(regionPanel).panel({
onExpand : function() {
       ...do something here after expand event completes...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify the following method in jquery.easyui.min.js,

```
function _30f(_310,_311){
    var _312=$.data(_310,"layout").panels;
    var _313=_314();
    var p=_312[_311];
    if(p.panel("options").onBeforeExpand.call(p)==false){
    return;
     }
   var _315="expand"+_311.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+_311.substring(1);
   _312[_315].panel("close");
   p.panel("panel").stop(true,true);
   p.panel("expand",false).panel("open").panel("resize",_313.collapse);
   p.panel("panel").animate(_313.expand,function(){
   _2e9(_310);
    p.panel("options").onExpand.call(p);//this is the added line
 });
```